# pip3 installing cbor2 throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, docker, ubuntu, pip

Probably not docker-related: I'm trying to install a couple of python packes inside a docker-container.

My Host is a *Raspberry Pi 4* and the *Docker Base Image* is a *Ubuntu 18.04*.

- **Host:** Raspberry Pi 4, `Linux raspberrypi 5.4.51-v7l+ armv7l GNU/Linux`
- **Docker Base Image:** `ubuntu:18.04`

I've installed python using just apt-get

```
RUN apt-get update & apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-pip ...
```

For installing the packages I'm using the regular pip command

```
RUN python3 -m pip install <packages>
```

Apparently, one of my packages (not sure which) requires `cbor2` but the installation throws an error:

```
...
Collecting cbor2
  Downloading cbor2-5.1.2.tar.gz (73 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o2fkfon2/cbor2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o2fkfon2/cbor2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-z3eibmqi
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o2fkfon2/cbor2/
    Complete output (19 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-o2fkfon2/cbor2/setup.py", line 68, in <module>
        **kwargs
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 121, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 491, in parse_config_files
        _Distribution.parse_config_files(self, filenames=filenames)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 395, in parse_config_files
        parser.read(filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 697, in read
        self._read(fp, filename)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1015, in _read
        for lineno, line in enumerate(fp, start=1):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
        return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 149: ordinal not in range(128)
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

This only seems to be an issue with `python3.6` (which is the default python3 version for Ubuntu 18.04).
If I'm manually compiling and installing python version 3.8 it seems to work perfectly. Did someone have a workaround for avoiding this error using python 3.6?

 I want to avoid the need to compile python 3.8 since I'm using a RPi Zero and this process takes **way too long to compile**.

 Also upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 is no possibility since docker and ubuntu 20.04 seems to have [problems with apt-get and GPG](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263284/apt-update-throws-signature-error-in-ubuntu-20-04-container-on-arm)

Comment: I suspect the problem is with a non-ascii character in [`setup.cfg`](https://github.com/agronholm/cbor2/blob/d92b4ba7938b5828a5e23ce8dfe26a356519006b/setup.cfg#L6). The bug was discussed here: https://github.com/agronholm/cbor2/issues/74. Try to reopen it if you need. Or change the locale to `C.utf-8`.

Comment: Does  not seem to work: ```Step 4/18 : RUN locale-gen C.utf-8
 ---> Running in ...
Error: 'C.utf-8' is not a supported language or locale
```

I temporally now using the workaroud from the link I gave in my answer and using ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `C.UTF-8`, `en_US.utf8`, etc…

Comment: `en_US.utf8` already tried, but did not work apparently... (got same error)

Comment: https://github.com/agronholm/cbor2/issues/74#issuecomment-599200921